# Google Fusion Tables API v1 and GeoJSON to Google Maps Utility

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using Google Fusion Tables API v1 to request point kml loaded in fusion tables in JSON format. I use this request:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1CNJWjLDYgBkJGZVslJ67Fak4DyqadEFIabzQ60&callback=dataHandler&key=AIzaSyKBzv-rs32Zat-8fDZuWwOXo7hCtpBR78"></script>
```

[View the request data](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%201CNJWjLDYgBkJGZVslJ67Fak4DyqadEFuIabzQ60&callback=dataHandler&key=AIzaSyCKBzv-rs32Zat-8fDZuWwOXo7hCtpBR78)

the callback function use [GeoJSON to Google Maps Utility](https://github.com/JasonSanford/GeoJSON-to-Google-Maps) to parse markers from the request. The geometry data are in the column idx 2 named 'geometry':

```
    function dataHandler(results) {
        var rows = results['rows'];
        for (var i in rows){
            var geometries = rows[i][2]['geometry'];
            //alert(geometries.coordinates)
            if (geometries) {
              var options = {
                "icon": "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
              };
              var overlay = new GeoJSON(geometries, options);
              if (overlay.error){
                alert("error in GeoJSON")
              }else{
                alert(map) // return undefined
                overlay.setMap(map); //not working
              } 
            }else {
              alert('No geometry column')
            }
          }
        }
```

there is no error in the JSON or the overlay created by GeoJSON Utility, but the google map var "map" is undefined in the function even if its globally defined. Thats why the overlay.setMap(map) is not working. I suppose the callback function is called before the var map is defined. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or a link that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle but I dont know how to display a map with this tool. http://jsfiddle.net/4u2yu/1/

Comment: I managed to make it works by pushing overlay in overlays array instead of doing overlay.setMap(map) in the callback function. Then I did the setMap(map) on each overlay of overlays in the initialize() function

Comment: You should post your code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM
 TABLE_ID&callback=dataHandler&key=API_KEY"></script>

    var map;
    var overlays = [];


    function initialize(){
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.75, -71.25),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < overlays.length; i++){
          overlays[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }


    function dataHandler(results) {
        var rows = results['rows'];
        var cols = results['columns'];
        for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++){
          if (cols[i] == 'geometry') {
            var ColIndex = i;
          }
        }
        if (!ColIndex){
          alert('Geometry column "geometry" not found.')
        }
        for (var i in rows){
          var geometries = rows[i][ColIndex]['geometry'];
          if (geometries) {
            var options = {
              "icon": "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
            };
            var overlay = new GeoJSON(geometries,options);
            if (overlay.error){
              alert("error in overlay")
            }else{
              overlays.push(overlay);
            } 
          }else {
            alert("error in geoJSON response")
          }
        }
```